# How to send a model which consist generic list from ajax call in mvc C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to call the controller from ajax and sending model data which consist some list of data inside it. I am getting the count correct for them but inside the list properties are coming null.

Controller:

```
public JsonResult InsertorUpdate(IncidentEdit incident)
        {
            try
            {

                SrvincidentDtls.TicketNo = incident.TicketNo;
                SrvincidentDtls.Priority = incident.Priority;
                SrvincidentDtls.Status = incident.Status;
                SrvincidentDtls.Title = incident.Title;

                SrvincidentDtls.IsActive = incident.IsActive;
                List<Comments> lstComm = new List<Comments>();
                if(incident.CommentList!=null )
                {
                    foreach (var comm in incident.CommentList)
                    {
                        Comments Comm = new Comments();
                        Comm.Comment = comm.Comments;
                        Comm.AddedBy = comm.AddedBy;
                        Comm.AddedBy_ID = comm.AddedBy_ID;
                        Comm.CreatedDate = comm.CreatedDate;
                        lstComm.Add(Comm);

                    }
                }

                SrvincidentDtls.Comments = lstComm.ToArray();
                SrvincidentDtls.Description = incident.Description;



                var result=proxyService.InsertorUpdateIncidentDetails(SrvincidentDtls);
                return Json(new { success = true, jvalue = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Model:

```
public class IncidentEdit
    {


        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public List<IncidentComments> CommentList { get; set; }
    }
```

Generic Class:

```
 public class IncidentComments
    {
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string AddedBy { get; set; }
        public string AddedBy_ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Ajax call:

```
 function InsertOrUpdate(){
          incidentDetails = {

                        Title: $("#txtTitle").val(),
                        Description: $("#txtDescription").val(),
                        Priority: $('#selPriority option:selected').val(),
                        Status: $('#selStatus option:selected').val(),
                        IsActive: 1,
                        CreatedDate :$('#spncrtdDt').text(),
                        CommentList:PopulateCommentList()

                    };

                    $.ajax({


                             type: "Get", //HTTP POST Method
                             url: insertORupdatUrl, // Controller/View
                             data: {incident:incidentDetails},
                             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                             success: function (data) {
    }
    });
    }
```

js function:

```
function PopulateCommentList() {

            var CommentList = [];
            var dtTable = $('#dvCommentTbl').DataTable();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (dtTable.row(i).data() != "" && dtTable.row(i).data() != null && dtTable.row(i).data() != undefined) {
                    CommentList.push({
                        Comments: dtTable.row(i).data()[1],
                        AddedBy: dtTable.row(i).data()[2],
                        AddedBy_ID: dtTable.row(i).data()[0],
                        CreatedDate: dtTable.row(i).data()[3]
                    });
                }


            }

            return CommentList;
        }
```

the count for comment list is coming fine but the data like Added_By,comments,Created Dtae all coming null.

Plz help.

Comment: In your controller Action method , are you able to debug the value of result , is having proper data inside.try put a break point here : return Json(new { success = true, jvalue = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     and check the value of result.

Comment: Can you see your console and check what data you are sending in side commentlist property? Also, if you can try with `JSON.parse(PopulateCommentList())`

Comment: json coming fine@Abdul

Comment: Ya after parsing also m getting value but the list there in controller showing null@just code

Answer (score 0):

You can take a variable like

```
var commlist=PopulateCommentList();
```

then populate it in your model json:

```
incidentDetails = {

                        Title: $("#txtTitle").val(),
                        Description: $("#txtDescription").val(),
                        Priority: $('#selPriority option:selected').val(),
                        Status: $('#selStatus option:selected').val(),
                        IsActive: 1,
                        CreatedDate :$('#spncrtdDt').text(),
                        CommentList:commlist

                    };
```

it will work as it work for me.